K6 configuration for more than 1000 Requests per second
I am using K6 to do some load testing but whatever configuration I give it I cannot get it to make more than ~1000 requests per second.
I’ve tried various scenarios to get the RPS much higher but the only way seems to be with more VUs however this causes very high load on the server.
When I use Jmeter load testing tool I can get 30,000 no problem (I’ve had 70,000) but I can’t get microsecond accuracy with Jmeter so hoping to move over to K6.
Some scenarios I have tried
{
  "scenarios": {
    "ramped_load_test": {
      "executor": "ramping-arrival-rate",
      "startRate": 1000,  // Start with 1000 requests per second
      "timeUnit": "1s",  // Requests per second
      "preAllocatedVUs": 350,  // Minimum virtual users (set slightly above 300)
      "maxVUs": 1000,  // Maximum VUs for scalability
      "stages": [
        { "duration": "1m", "target": 5000 }, 
        { "duration": "2m", "target": 15000 }, 
        { "duration": "2m", "target": 30000 }, 
        { "duration": "15m", "target": 30000 } 
      ],
      "gracefulStop": "30s" 
    }
  },
  "noConnectionReuse": false,
  "insecureSkipTLSVerify": true,
  "userAgent": "MyK6UserAgentString/1.0"
}

and then a constant rate scenario
{
  "scenarios": {
    "constant_load_test": {
      "executor": "constant-arrival-rate",
      "rate": 30000,
      "timeUnit": "1s",
      "duration": "15m",
      "preAllocatedVUs": 350,
      "maxVUs": 1000,
      "gracefulStop": "30s"
    }
  },
  "noConnectionReuse": false,
  "insecureSkipTLSVerify": true,
  "userAgent": "MyK6UserAgentString/1.0"
}

however in all of these I only ever seem to get around 1000 Requests per second but I can get multiple connections (virtual users). See pictures.
It doesn’t matter if i have 1 connection or 1000 i still cant get the requests per second up.
My objective in an ideal world is to ramp up to 30,000 requests per second over 1 minute and then hold 30,000 requests per second for an hour.
I want to then vary the number of connections that are producing this 30,000 so i can see the CPU load etc on the server being tested based on how many connections are being made.
Could someone please advise me where I’m going wrong here? Thanks

Have you had a look at https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/set-up/fine-tune-os/ already?

30k requests per second with 1k users means every user needs to execute 30 requests per second. This means a single request must take at most 33 milliseconds to complete, otherwise you will be running out of VUs. What's the response time of your service under test? Can it handle 30k rps while keeping the response times below 30 milliseconds?

hey @knittl yeah I have no issues even higher than 30k - its been tested at 70k and keeping even below 10ms. The issues I am having are purely on the load tester side not the application. I don't quite understand why each user is not able to make paralell requests in K6 and Jmeter can do that.

Because each user (VU) in k6 is modeled as a separate "process" (goroutine). A single VU can only make a single request at a time (unless you utilize http.batch). It's a design decision intended to make it easier to understand the state of each VU.
